# T's adjoint inverse = T inverse adjoint?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to ask for any linear operator $T: V \rightarrow V$
$$ (T^*)^{-1} = (T^{-1})^*$$
Is it true? If yes, how to show it is right? If not, under what conditions it might be true?

Comment: So you are asking whether $T^*$ is the inverse of $(T^{-1}^*$. What would that mean? How is the inverse defined?

Comment: I guess it is same as whether $T^*$ is the inverter of $(T^{-1})^*$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is invertible. Then for any $u,v \in V$, 
$$\langle u, (T^{-1})^* T^* v \rangle = \langle T^{-1} u , T^* v \rangle = \langle T T^{-1} u, v \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle \Rightarrow (T^{-1})^* T^* = I \Rightarrow  (T^{-1})^* = (T^*)^{-1}.$$